# How they did the imo/ebuddy app on android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm a beginner in android development and I've seen the use of activities, and even if they look pretty related in the application, code-wise they are almost totally independent. I became curious how ebuddy and imo manage multiple chats open.

Are they one activity only and then only change the parameters when we go back to them? or are they generated in runtime?

If anyone can explain how its done, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Android activites can use a Service to run things in the background, then when the activity is started, it pulls information needed from the background service, essentially persisting the data between activities.

All apps that you see with "notifications" and that sort of thing use background services like this.

Comment: right... so if i want to store an actual activity i have to use it as a background service? [edit] i've used an app i made then written something in the texfield, went to another activity then came back and what ive written was there

Comment: You do not store an activity, an activity is not data, it is closer to a process.  If you want to persist information BETWEEN activities, you can use a service, or use onSavedInstanceState().  Activity switching is treated as a first in, last out stack.  I.e. if you hit back, you lose the activity you just exited, but if you move forward, the last activity you were in is saved.

Comment: thanks, learner here ^^ thanks for the help, but i didnt yet know how they made multiple chats, i mean how they did it with activities, they used only one? multiple? thanks

Comment: There is only one active activity on an Android device at any time.  You can have multiple chats by using a service to control things in the background, and calling on components of that service when the user requests them or when the service does something.  [Please read this entire page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) :)